# Axis2 intallation make on macosx

Tags: macos, makefile, axis2c

I am getting following error during axis2c installation:

unrecognized command line option "-Wno-long-double"

macos 10.8.3
gcc 4.2.1

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Remove that unsupported option from `util/configure` and build Axis2/C again.

```
sed -i 's/-Wno-long-double//g' util/configure
#./configure ....
```